# Access closest/first value recursively in self reference Model (Tree) utilizing EF Core

Tags: c#, database, postgresql, entity-framework, linq

I have a simple File System-like hierachy which has both Files and Folders, I'm having issues with retrieving information which is nested in their children or in their parent, or parent's parent, etc...

These are a representation of my Model's classes

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public bool File { get; set; }

    public virtual Item? Parent { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Parent")]
    public virtual List<Item> Children { get; set; }

    public Profile? Profile { get; set; }
}

public class Profile
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

I need to access all items and their children who reside inside a parent with a certain Profile, right now I'm doing it like this:

```
_context.Items.Where(i => profiles.Contains(i.Profile.Id))
```

This works with a shallow hierarchy:

- FolderA - (Profile)

  - FileA
  - FileB

But if we attempt something deeper it wouldn't work:

- FolderA - (Profile)

  - Folder B

    - FileA
    - FileB

So I adapted by chaining these checks like this:

```
_context.Items.Where(i => (profiles.Contains(i.Profile.Id) | profiles.Contains(i.Parent.Profile.Id) | ...))
```

I chained as much as I need to support my client's need, but it's not flexible at all...

I tought about creating an inverse property to Items inside the Profile class and attempt to get all it's children items by flattening the tree but all I found were recursive for loops and with 1700000 entries I believe this needs to be done at DB level (If possible of course)

Comment: Yes, you need database support and probably a view. In all databases you'd need a hierarchical CTE at the very least. That's not the most performant way though, as the server still has to recurse to find children. A better option is to use `hierachyid` in SQL Server or [ltree](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ltree.html) in PostgreSQL to create an indexable column that represents the hierarchy path, eg `1.23.45.678`. With such a type searching for children becomes a simple prefix search using the root's ltree value.

Comment: NpgSql [supports the LTree type and functions](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/translations.html#ltree-functions)

Answer (score 0):

> I need to access all items and their children who reside inside a parent with a certain Profile

How about

```
var q = db.Set<Item>()
          .Include(e => e.Children)
          .ThenInclude(c => c.Children)
          .Where(i => profiles.Contains(i.Profile.Id));
```

Comment: What if there are 3 levels of nesting or more? That's not something that can be solved with LINQ and even if LINQ could generate a recursive CTE it would be slower than using a hierarchical type like SQL Server's `hierarchyid` or PostgreSQL's `ltree`. This is one case where the ORM abstraction breaks down

Comment: AFAIK that's not what OP is asking for.  "all items and their children who reside inside a parent with a certain Profile" is just three levels.

Comment: The idea was to dynamically go through all the levels without the need to daisy chain ThenInclude or using multiple Contains clausules inside Where.

And in this case you proposed the variable q will contain only the top level Items, I suppose one could fix it with a SelectMany, but in the end it's just more hardcoded depth, which is what I'm trying to avoid.

I'm guessing CTEs and ltrees are what I'm supposed to implement here...

Comment: Also you can do Lazy Loading to traverse the hierarchy dynamically, although that will generate more SQL queries.